# What is the underside of the bed called?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

If a child is under the bed and while crawling out he bumps his head against the underside of the bed, what word can be used for the underside of the bed?

I have found a word bed base,does it sound right in the this situation?

Answer (score 1):

It might be a **bed frame**, **bedboard** or **box springs**.  An image search will quickly show you which best describes that particular bed.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, the clearest thing to say would be "underside of the bed".

There are different types of beds that have different types of "undersides". A "platform bed" is one that has some sort of flat surface or frame that you can rest the mattress on directly. A "frame bed" has a rectangular frame that you sit a boxspring on, and then the mattress sits on top of the boxspring. Sometimes instead of using a boxspring people will just use a bedboard, basically a flat board, usually covered with fabric, to sit in the frame and then the mattress sits on top of that. Sometimes instead of a bedboard you use a series of slats connected by cloth, looking kind of like a ladder. Sorry if my descriptions of these aren't entirely clear. Maybe there are other arrangements that I'm not thinking of.

I don't recall hearing the phrase "bed base". I'd guess it's the same as "platform", but I don't know.

So a child bumping his head on the "underside" of a bed might be bumping his head against the frame, a bedboard, boxsprings, slats, or maybe something else. If you're just trying to say that the child bumped his head on something under there, you probably don't care exactly what. It's probably not relevant exactly what kind of bed this is and explaining it would likely just distract from the story. So the best thing to say would just be "the underside of the bed".

I've heard and read stories that go off on a tangent describing some irrelevant detail. I'm suddenly reminded of a lecture I heard years ago by an American reporter who was in Nazi Germany before and during World War 2. He had some fascinating things to say about what went on, but he repeatedly bogged down his stories in irrelevant detail. Like at one point he said that the first time he saw Hitler was at some party rally. And then he said that the reporters were all put off to the side slightly, viewing the stage from about a 30 degree angle. Or maybe it was 40 degrees. Not straight on, but from an angle. Kind of to the side. And he went on and on talking about the angle rather than getting to the point about what was said or done at this meeting. It was maddening!